# Don't process html in value of input

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have an entry in my mysql table that contains html code:

```
<p>Hello!</p>
```

This shows up fine when I want to display it `echo $entry`

but when I place `echo $entry` in a textarea's value, it executes the code instead of showing it.

Is there any way to stop the code from executing and show the tags or convert to and from `&lt;&gt;`

Here is the code:

```
echo "<label for=\"details\">Details:</label><textarea id=\"details\" cols=\"60\" rows=\"10\" name=\"details\" value=\"" . $row["details"]."\"></textarea>";
```

Here is the entry:

```
<p><ol><li>HKCU/Software/Microsoft/Windows/NT/CurrentVersion/WindowsLegacy/DefaultPrinterMode<li> Set to 0 (on)</ol>
```

Comment: What would you expect in the textarea? You can't display a paragraph in the textarea, just text

Comment: Textarea content goes **inside** the element.

Comment: Hi, im hoping to show <p><ol><li>HKCU/Software/Microsoft/Windows/NT/CurrentVersion/WindowsLegacy/DefaultPrinterMode<li>
Set to 0 (on)</ol>which I can then change and update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to escape special characters. You can do that with [htmlspecialchars()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php).

What's more, You should not set a value to the textarea but rather write it in its content:

```
<textarea>
<?php /* some code here */ ?> 
</textarea>
```

Comment: Thanks everyone for your answers and malutki5200 A.R putting the code in between the <textarea> instead of value= worked

echo "<label for=\"details\">Details:</label><textarea id=\"details\" cols=\"60\" rows=\"10\" name=\"details\">". $row["details"]."</textarea>";

Answer (score 0):

i think this this will do it

```
<textarea><?php echo  $row['details'];?></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

try to save data lik

```
ascii_to_entities($this->input->post('ur_textara_name'));
```

and at the time of display

```
entities_to_ascii()
```